# Muliple JQuery UI autocomplete select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I found this demo [autocomplete select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox), the code works great.
I needed to have more than one autocomplete in my page but the jQuery autocomplete did not apply to more than one `<select>` (the first one).

```
<select  id="combobox" name = "type">
<option>...
<option>...
<option>...
</select>
<select  id="combobox" name = "status">
<option>...
<option>...
<option>...
</select>
```

I am new to jQuery. I can't figure this out by myself, hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find the solution very simple all i needed to do is to declare more ids for the extra select i have so in the JQuery UI source go to this script

```
    $(function() {
    $("#combobox").combobox();
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
        $("#combobox").toggle();
    });
});
```

and add the extra select ids like this

```
    $(function() {
    $("#combobox").combobox();
    $("#combobox2").combobox();
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
        $("#combobox").toggle();
    });
});
```

so now all you need to do is to call each select with its own id

```
<select  class="combobox" name = "type">
<option>...
<option>...
<option>...
</select>
<select  class="combobox2" name = "status">
<option>...
<option>...
<option>...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs **must** be unique. Use classes instead.

```
<select  class="combobox" name = "type">
<option>...
<option>...
<option>...
</select>
<select  class="combobox" name = "status">
<option>...
<option>...
<option>...
</select>
```

Comment: I did try that already but class="combobox" dose not apply the autocomplete, it has to be id. I think the only possibility is to change the JQuery code

Comment: No, it doesn't have to use IDs. Why don't you create a jsFiddle.net example of the problem you're having so we can all see it and reproduce it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hJCU4/1/  you can try using class instead of id but that dosent work well this code works fine but if u can do better post it (jsfiddle seem to not support all the style normally the autocomplete look much better but that's not the point here )